# Sorting a dictionary with list values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm pulling some data from a redis key-value store.
The data is in the format of a list. However Im pulling them and placing them into a dictionary

```
{ name1: [ int1, int2] }
{ name2: [ int11,int22]}
..etc...
```

I want to create a sorted dictionary where the entries pulled are sorted by `int2` value in the list. How can I do this sorted and itemgetter?

So as a result I'd like a sorted dictionary such that `names` are sorted according to the value of `int2` of the list values in descending order

I tried `sorted(data, key=itemgetter(2))` but this obviously did not work :(

Comment: What do you mean *"a sorted dictionary"*?

Comment: I mean a dictionary where the name keys are placed in the order defined by the sort. so {'name1': [1,4] , 'name2':[1,3], 'name3':[1,2], etc. }

Comment: Dictionaries are *arbitrarily ordered* data structures; if order matters, they are the wrong choice. Perhaps look into `collections.OrderedDict`, or just a list of tuples `[(name1, [int1, int2]), ...]`.

Comment: If your names are already sorted in the order you want, you might use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: I will look into OrderedDict, thanks. The only reason why order does matter is because the data will be compared and subsequently used in an html table, sorted by the last int in the list.

Answer (score 1):

To get a sorted list of all names, you have to get the value to your key:

```
sorted_names = sorted(data, key=lambda k: data[k][1])
```

Comment: You may need to check your lambda expression

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

```
sorted(d.items() , key=lambda x: d[x[0]][1])
```

This would return tuples sorted by the second element in the list of value of the dictionary.

Please note, dictionary does not have a concept of `order` in its elements , that is you cannot `sort` a dictionary per se.

Comment: So it seemd that redis is returning an odd type of list here when I use 
    r.lrange(key,0,-1)
ret = v : ['[1752041, 49210]']
This is what Im getting back, so i cant actually parse this properly...

Comment: The redis server instance

Answer (score 0):

As per [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary).

So, you cannot get an ordered dictionary, if you want to keep the same data type ,i.e: dictionary and order the items, use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they
>   remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an
>   ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys
>   were first added.

So if you want to get an ordered dictionary sorted by int2 (Example from Python docs)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])) #Order by Value

print d
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
```